# Is in-memory write-cache and ZIL data both written through TXG commits?

Tags: zfs

ZFS nowadays has an interval of 5 seconds for doing TXG (Transaction Group Commits) of the in-memory write-cache.. How and after how long is ZIL data committed to the rotational media from say, an SSD SLOG?

Does ZIL commits also happen after 5 seconds (of course as and when the system load permits?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "ZIL commit". In fact, blocks are *always* dirtied in the memory cache upon a write request, no matter if it is synchronous or asynchronous. The ZIL just adds *persistency* for synchronous write requests.

So if you have a separate ZFS log device for your pool, you may observe that it is only taking write load, data is not read off it under normal circumstances. Only if you have an unclean shutdown of your pool (e.g. by a hard reset or a power failure), the intent log is being read and applied to the pool's data as the pool is being loaded.

The dirtied blocks are flushed upon a TXG commit, the type of operation does not matter much.

Comment: I had heard something similar to that effect.. But after reading a few articles such as [these] (http://constantin.glez.de/blog/2010/07/solaris-zfs-synchronous-writes-and-zil-explained), I think ZIL is used for synchronous writes so that calls in the "wait()" state could return quickly, w/o waiting for the slower rotational disks commits..  Dirty data is then later on committed to the slower drives.. Please go though this article, and see if we can still agree? :)

Comment: @Junaid the ZIL *is* used to persistently back synchronous writes. But it is ***not read*** again unless you have an unclean shutdown. There simply is no need to read the ZIL - the block is being dirtied in the ARC so it can be read off the ARC during the commit operation. This is also the reason why the ZFS log device does not need to be larger than your ARC cache size.

Comment: OK your points make sense.. This is how it's done in Linux storage subsystem too, AFAIK (with dirty buffers and such).  But I still need to re-read those articles :)